# Is there a nice shortcut in Pandas to restore real values from first-order differenced timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got `timeseries = (training, test)`, and then I used Pandas `.diff()` operator for `training` part of timeseries (`diff_training_ts`) to make my timeseries stationary, and then I predicted test values using `diff_training_set`.

Obviously, my predicted values are not true yet, I have to `integrate` them.

And now I'd like to calculate `sqrt(rmse(test, predicted))`, the problem is that I have to restore the true values and I wrote a piece of code using `cumsum()` and others, but it looks hacky (and there's a bug, too). Is there a nice shortcut in Pandas for this kind of operation?

**UPD**:
Here's a result if I remove cumsum: imgur.com/a/OEiDXXk But here's an example: source data: `df = 3 10 12 15 4` where `{3, 10, 12} = training`, `{15, 4} = test`. After `df = df.diff()` -> `diff = {NaN 7 2 3 -11}` -> `diff_training = {7, 2}` , `diff_test = {3, -11}` -> `diff_test.cumsum() = {3, -8}`, `seed = 3`, `term_to_add = 12` and then to receive true test values we can `test = {3 + 12, -8 + 12}`.

Comment: How do you know whether 1 came from 2 - 1 or 100000 - 99999?

Comment: @coldspeed My homemade implementation takes a `seed = train[0]` basically, then I sum up all the the training diffs -> `term_to_add = seed + diff_training.sum()`.

Then I predict test values and to make them real I do `test = test.cumsum(); test += term_to_add;` The issue is that I clearly need to do cumsum() but if I remove that line it works (at least visually) OK.

Comment: Is this what you're asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918013/undo-a-series-diff

Comment: @RafaelC yeah, but it's yet another bicycle thing. I believe you can't use loops with numpy.

Comment: @coldspeed here's my homemade code with a bug (about cumsum): https://pastebin.com/raw/WXpbj7Cp

Comment: Here's a result if I remove cumsum: https://imgur.com/a/OEiDXXk

But here's an example:
source data: `df = 3 10 12 15 4` where `{3, 10, 12} = training`, `{15, 4} = test`. After `df = df.diff() -> diff = {NaN 7 2 3 -11} -> diff_training = {7, 2} , diff_test = {3, -11} -> diff_test.cumsum() = {3, -8}, seed = 3, term_to_add = 12` and then to receive true test values we can `test = {3 + 12, -8 + 12}`.